When a rocket company publishes a list price for a launch, is that what a customer can expect to pay, or are additional fees typically added on?
The kinds of "additional fees" that I'm thinking of might include things like sales tax, "spaceport fees", mandatory insurance, etc.
I'm trying to get a sense of how much a company that needs launch services should budget to cover launch costs, over and above the list price of the launch, if they want to have a sound business plan.

I don't think that this is a question where you can provide a generalized answer. It's like asking, "how much am I going to pay in taxes this year?" where the answer is (a) it depends and (b) highly complex. While there are additional costs beyond the launch provider's "sticker price", the industry is still so young and small that there really aren't any templates you can plug in your parameters and then get a straightforward prediction.

You don’t want to know what the checked bag fee is…

There are lots of variables. Quoted prices usually come with a lot of if/but assumptions. Firstly rockets come in different configurations so for Falcon 9 there would be launches with:
Booster return to landing site, cheaper as no need for the transfer barge but smaller payload. Booster landing at sea, more expensive but more payload. There are also probably sub options as to how far out the barge needs to be. And Booster expended, most expensive but highest payload. Then there are Falcon heavy options as well.
There is also the question of exactly when the launch must occur. If it has to be launched at a specific time on a specific day then that will come at a premium as all other launches will have to work round it. If it can be launched at say any time in November 2025 then that should be cheaper as there is plenty of warning and if anyone needs to shuffle the launch schedule there is a lot more wriggle room.
Yet another issue is ground services. Does the payload need any special kit dry nitrogen purge? temperature control? clean room? horizontal or vertical stacking, helium? etc  $$$
Then there's the issue of ride sharing. If you are agreeable to sharing a launch with another customer or group of customers after a similar trajectory then you should get a discount.
Then there's insurance. At many tens of millions of dollars and a failure rate that is not entirely clear cut even on the best rockets at perhaps a few percent down to 0.1% (hard to say exactly) It won't be that cheap  $$$.
Other than that there are range costs as notices have to be put out for a launch and in some cases road closures, warnings, paperwork etc.
On the topic of paperwork there may be all sorts of validation and verification checks required, especially if you are NASA or the US air force. These might be required as a one off or might be needed each flight. The military might also have a range of security requirements all of which may come at an extra cost.  $$$
